# The multi-part identifier "tbl.pendingeffort" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting the error:

> The multi-part identifier "tbl.pendingeffort" could not be bound.

while executing this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spc_updateStudyPlan]
    @studyplandt StudyPlanType READONLY

AS
BEGIN

UPDATE studyplan SET tbl.pendingeffort = dt.effortinminutes
    FROM @studyplandt dt Inner join studyPlan tbl ON tbl.id = dt.id

END
```

Can you please help me in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an alias on the left hand side of assignment in the `SET` clause. Nor do you need to, you've already identified which table is being updated after the `UPDATE` keyword:

```
UPDATE studyplan SET pendingeffort = dt.effortinminutes
                 FROM @studyplandt dt Inner join studyPlan tbl ON tbl.id = dt.id
/*     ^
       |
       |This is the only table that the UPDATE statement can affect    */
```

Comment: How how can I fix my query?

Comment: @JackDaniels - as in my answer, just remove the `tbl.` before `pendingeffort` in the `SET` clause.